# What are my options to get an bird's eye view of the Niagara falls?

Tags: vantage-points, niagara-falls

What options do I have to see the Niagara Falls from a bird's eye view?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The views are pretty sweet from some of the hotels. Here's one from a room that cost me $25 extra for a "falls view room":

[image: Falls view]

Really, it's from the room:

[image: Falls from hotel room with window frame showing]

I'm pretty sure it was the Sheraton.

Update: since someone mentioned the Skylon tower, here's a shot (on a fairly old cellphone) from the restaurant.

[image: US falls from Skylon tower]

Go up for dinner on a night they have fireworks, and you can see fireworks from above, which is very cool.

Comment: Based on the angle (and the window frames!) this looks like the old "Sheraton Fallsview" which is now the "Marriott Gateway on the Falls".

Comment: And at this time of year you can get some sweet, sweet deals on Niagara Falls hotel rooms.

Answer (score 13):

You can do a helicopter tour, many tour agencies provide this kind of tour on both the USA and Canada sides. Prices are a little bit expensive ($110+) but it's worth every penny.

I picked up random tour agencies from Google search, one on the [Canadian side](http://www.niagara-helicopters.com/home.php) and the other on the [American side](http://rainbowairinc.com/Our_Tours.html).

[image: Helicopter tour]

Furthermore, there is a [skydiving center near Niagara falls](http://www.niagaraskydive.com/main.html), not sure if you will be able to see the falls from that high but you can give it a try for $299.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the hotels and helicopter tours that are already mentioned, it is also possible, to access one of the two towers that were built for that purpose:

The [Konica Minolta Tower Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konica_Minolta_Tower_Centre) has a visitor platform at 99 meters and offers a view over the Horseshoes Falls.

[image]

A more popular option is the [Skylon Tower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylon_Tower) that offers a really great view over all of the falls.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

We stayed at the [Crowne Plaza Hotel](http://www.niagarafallscrowneplazahotel.com/) with a falls view room and we had great views of both the American and Canadian falls. We fell asleep watching the light show on both! Exceptional!